# How to replace for loop to reduce the running time?

Tags: python, numpy

Here is my function to set value of `cropped_inputs_final` array (528 * 250) from `G1_index` array (528 * 250), `cropped_inputs_index` (528) and `inputs_data_list` array (16384 * 256).

```
for i in range(cropped_inputs_final.shape[0]):
  for j in range(cropped_inputs_final.shape[1]):
    a1=G1_index[i][j]
    b1=int(cropped_inputs_index[i])
    cropped_inputs_final[i][j]=inputs_data_list[a1][b1]
```

However, this for loop spends too much time.

Is there any way to replace for loop with numpy (or any else) to reduce the running time?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please provide a sample of your arrays and what you expect in the output.

Comment: There are just arrays composed of numbers. I want to make new array (cropped_inputs_final) by inserting value of (inputs_data_list) at desired locations obtained from (G1_index) and (cropped_inputs_index).

Comment: When you're using numpy, try to avoid writing explicit loops. Use its built-in operations so that it can optimize.

Comment: Also, for 2-d arrays, use `array[i,j]` rather than `a[i][j]`

Comment: Show input and output on small matrices or this can't be solved...

Comment: Please read [mre]